# Python os.walk() umlauts u'\u0308'

Tags: python, unicode, os.walk

I'm on a OSX machine and running Python 2.7. I'm trying to do a os.walk on a smb share.

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("./test"):
        for filename in filenames:

            print filename

            matchObj = re.match( r".*ö.*",filename,re.UNICODE)
```

if i use the above code it works as long as the filename do not contain umlauts.
In my shell the umlauts are printed fine but when I copy them back to a utf8 formated Textdeditor (in my case Sublime), I get:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2qy5.png)
Expected:

```
filename.jpeg
filename_ö.jpg
```

Of course the regex fails with that. 
if i hardcode the filename like:

```
re.match( r".*ö.*",'filename_ö',re.UNICODE)
```

it works fine.

I tried:

```
os.walk(u"./test")
filename.decode('utf8')
```

but gives me:

```
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0308' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`u'\u0308'` are the dots above the umlauts.

I'm overlooking something stupid i guess?

Comment: In Python 2.x, you need to pass a Unicode object to `os.walk()` else you'll get an encoded string, using the raw filename in Unix or 8bit charset in Windows (In OS X, the filename is always UTF-8 encoded)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unicode characters can be represented in various forms; there's "ö", but then there's also the possibility to represent that same character using an "o" and separate *combining diacritics*. OS X generally prefers the separated variant, and your editor doesn't seem to handle that very gracefully, nor do these two separate characters match your regex.

You need to *normalize* your Unicode data if you require one way or the other in particular. See [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). You want the NFC normalized form.

Comment: Unicode normalization is [not the only issue in the code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33678596/4279).

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues:

1. The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2qy5.png) as [@deceze explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33647372/4279) is due to Unicode normalization. Note: it is not necessary for the codepoints to look different e.g., ö (U+00f6) and ö (U+006f U+0308) look the same in my browser
2. `r".*ö.*"` is a *bytestring* in Python 2 and the value depends on the encoding declaration at the top of your Python source file (something like: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`) e.g., if the declared encoding is utf-8 then `'ö'` bytestring is a sequence of two *bytes*: `'\xc3\xb6'`.

   There is no way for the regex engine to know the actual encoding that should be used to interpret input bytestrings.

   You should not use bytestrings, to represent text; **use Unicode** instead (either use `u''` literals or add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top)
3. `filename.decode('utf8')` raises `UnicodeEncodeError` if you use `os.walk(u"./test")` because `filename` is Unicode already. Python 2 tries to encode `filename` implicitly using the default encoding that is `'ascii'`. **Do not decode Unicode**: drop `.decode('utf-8')`

btw, the last two issues are impossible in Python 3: `r".*ö.*"` is a Unicode literal, and you can't create a bytestring with literal non-ascii characters there, and there is no `.decode()` method (you would get `AttributeError` if you try to decode Unicode). You could run your script on Python 3, to detect Unicode-related bugs.

Comment: The OP isn't passing a Unicode to `os.walk()`, although they should be. You might want to update point 3 to recommend passing Unicode and dropping `.decode()`

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: read the question. OP have tried several variants. One of them `os.walk(u"./test")` i.e., with Unicode.